# Child Vue component data doesn't load on first page render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

In my Vue app I have some child components that previously worked, ie. their respective data loaded fine inside the parent component.

I initially achieved this by adding a key to my child component, a solution that I found online as the recommended way to update data of child components dynamically.The idea is that a component will update automatically any time the key changes.

`<upcoming-events :key="rerenderWidgets"/>`

I am incrementing the `rerenderWidgets` value like so. The child data should be ready after the Promises are finished. The following code runs in the `method()` lifecycle hook after checking if it is the first page load.

```
const promisesArray = [this.loadPrivate(),this.loadPublic()]
      await Promise.all(promisesArray).then(async() => {
        await this.getCurrentParticipants().then(async(results) => {
         this.currentParticipants = results
         this.rerenderWidgets += 1
    
     })
})
```

This worked for a while but the child components are no longer loading their data in the Parent until after the second page visit. The `renderWidgets` gets incremented but somehow the data is now not updated. I don't think I changed anything that could have broken it, but obviously something has.

The child component itself has functions which get data from a module whose data should be ready once the above Promises are done, so I am not sure why it no longer works.

I also tried using the following code in the `updated()` hook that as it is supposed to run after the page has fully rendered. I figured all of the data should be ready when this function is called. But it doesn't work and seems to invoke a loop that shows the alert repeatedly.

```
 updated() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
   alert('rerender....')
   this.rerenderWidgets += 1
  })
```

If anyone can tell me what might be going wrong and how I might fix it I'd much appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I understand you have non-reactive data in your child component and therefore need to get them reloaded?

Comment: rerenderWidgets is a hack that shouldn't be generally used unless you have a bunch of code that was designed the wrong way and it's too costly to refactor it. rerenderWidgets is assigned asynchronously so assigning it in updated doesn't make sense and will result in infinite loop. It should be as you expect, unless you have multiple copies of the same component with the same key. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case.

Comment: Completely agree with @EstusFlask. It is hard to say but this seems like a clue: *The child component itself has functions which get data from a module*. If the child is using `methods` (maybe in combination with `created` or `mounted` hooks) to get the data from the store, it is bad design. In such cases (especially with async data) computed props is the right solution most of the time...

Comment: Also your async code is really strange. Why you use `async` and `then` together? Either use one or the other. Mixing it like that seems unnecessary and really confusing...

Comment: @Michal Levý thanks for the feedback. I am absolutely sure that it is a case of bad design. The rerenderWidgets never felt right to me, but it worked..until it didn't. I am struggling a bit with computed properties and, while I understand the core concept, I haven't been able to find an example of what I need to do - getting dynamic data that is fetched inside my child to show in the parent on the first page load. Also, should the computed property be in the parent or the child? Anything I have found online are very basic single component examples usually using a button to fire the function.

Comment: I would suggest to delete this question (as it is really unanswerable in current form) and open new one - leave out the `:key` "hack", show important code - child component, how it is used in the parent, how are the data retrieved and made available to both components - something like [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would by really great

Comment: @MichalLevý as per your suggestion, I've tried to rewrite with an MRE. I hope that helps clarify the problem a bit. It's driving me nuts! ;D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977315/vue-child-component-not-displaying-dynamic-data-on-first-page-load