# Vue child component not displaying dynamic data on first page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-props

Given the code below, my child component alerts trigger before any of the code in the Parent mounted function.

As a result it appears the child has already finished initialization before the data is ready and therefor won't display the data until it is reloaded.

The data itself comes back fine from the API as the raw JSON displays inside the `v-card` in the layout.

My question is how can I make sure the data requested in the Parent is ready BEFORE the child component loads? Anything I have found focuses on static data passed in using props, but it seems this completely fails when the data must be fetched first.

Inside the `mounted()` of the Parent I have this code which is retrieves the data.

```
const promisesArray = [this.loadPrivate(),this.loadPublic()]
      await Promise.all(promisesArray).then(() => {
      console.log('DATA ...') // fires after the log in Notes component
      this.checkAttendanceForPreviousTwoWeeks().then(()=>{
        this.getCurrentParticipants().then((results) => {     
                  this.currentP = results
                  this.notesArr = this.notes // see getter below   
        })
```

The getter that retrieves the data in the parent

```
  get notes() {
    const newNotes = eventsModule.getNotes
    return newNotes
  }
```

My component in the parent template:

```
<v-card light elevation="">
    {{ notes }} // Raw JSON displays correctly here
   // Passing the dynamic data to the component via prop
   <Notes v-if="notes.length" :notesArr="notes"/>
</v-card>
```

The Child component:

```
...
  // Pickingn up prop passed to child
  @Prop({ type: Array, required: true })
      notesArr!: object[]

  constructor()
    {
      super();    
      alert(`Notes : ${this.notesArr}`) // nothing here 
      this.getNotes(this.notesArr)    
    }

 async getNotes(eventNotes){
    // THIS ALERT FIRES BEFORE PROMISES IN PARENT ARE COMPLETED
    alert(`Notes.getNotes CALL.. ${eventNotes}`) // eventNotes = undefined
    this.eventChanges = await eventNotes.map(note => {
      return {
        eventInfo: {
          name: note.name,
          group: note.groupNo || null,
          date: note.displayDate,
        },     
        note: note.noteToPresenter
      }
    })
  }
...
```

I am relatively new to Vue so forgive me if I am overlooking something basic. I have been trying to fix it for a couple of days now and can't figure it out so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So it seems you are using [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) ....correct ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Vue, I really recommend reading the entire documentation of it and the tools you are using - [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) (which is Vue plugin adding API for declaring Vue components as classes)

1. [Caveats of Class Component - Always use lifecycle hooks instead of `constructor`](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/caveats.html#always-use-lifecycle-hooks-instead-of-constructor)

So instead of using `constructor()` you should move your code to `created()` [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created)

This should be enough to fix your code in this case BUT only because the usage of the `Notes` component is guarded by `v-if="notes.length"` in the Parent - the component will get created only after `notes` is not empty array

This is not enough in many cases!

2. `created()` lifecycle hook (and `data()` function/hook) is executed only once for each component. The code inside is **one time initialization**. So when/if parent component changes the content of `notesArr` prop (sometimes in the future), the `eventChanges` will not get updated. Even if you know that parent will never update the prop, note that for performance reasons Vue tend to reuse existing component instances when possible when rendering lists with `v-for` or [switching between components of the same type](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key) with `v-if`/`v-else` - instead of destroying existing and creating new components, Vue just updates the props. App suddenly looks broken for no reason...

This is a mistake many unexperienced users do. You can find many questions here on SO like "my component is not reactive" or "how to force my component re-render" with many answers suggesting using `:key` hack or using a watcher ....which sometimes work but is almost always much more complicated then the right solution

Right solution is to write your components (if you can - sometimes it is not possible) as [pure components](https://medium.com/technofunnel/working-with-react-pure-components-166ded26ae48) (article is for React but the principles still apply). Very important tool for achieving this in Vue are [computed propeties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)

So instead of introducing `eventChanges` data property (which [might or might not be reactive](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#data) - this is not clear from your code), you should make it computed property which is using `notesArr` prop directly:

```
get eventChanges() {
   return this.notesArr.map(note => {
     return {
       eventInfo: {
         name: note.name,
         group: note.groupNo || null,
         date: note.displayDate,
       },     
       note: note.noteToPresenter
     }
   })
}
```

Now whenever `notesArr` prop is changed by the parent, `eventChanges` is updated and the component will re-render

**Notes:**

- You are overusing `async`. Your `getNotes` function does not execute any asynchronous code so just remove it.
- also do not mix `async` and `then` - it is confusing

Either:

```js
const promisesArray = [this.loadPrivate(),this.loadPublic()]
await Promise.all(promisesArray)
await this.checkAttendanceForPreviousTwoWeeks()
const results = await this.getCurrentParticipants()
this.currentP = results
this.notesArr = this.notes
```

or:

```js
const promisesArray = [this.loadPrivate(),this.loadPublic()]
Promise.all(promisesArray)
  .then(() => this.checkAttendanceForPreviousTwoWeeks())
  .then(() => this.getCurrentParticipants())
  .then((results) => {     
    this.currentP = results
    this.notesArr = this.notes
  })
```

[Great learning resource](https://javascript.info/async)

Comment: Thanks so much for this Michal. You have given me some great pointers to move forward with. I thought that because I was instantiating a class the  `constructor()` function could be used, like regular JS. But, yes I agree, `vue-class-component` plugin changes everything. I am going to try a refactor of the entire component with your suggestions and hopefully it will solve the issue. Thanks again for your time and effort.